# leaflet mouse event on circlemarket not working

Tags: javascript, leaflet

```
function createCamera(camLoc, bear){
    var camera = L.circleMarker(camLoc,{radius: 8, fill: true,});
    camera.addTo(map);
    camera.on('mouseover', function (e) {
        console.log("mouse over");
    })

    // var bearingLineLength= 8000;//M
    // var endpoint =getCameraDestinationPoint(camLoc[0], camLoc[1], bear, bearingLineLength );
    // drawnBearing[i]= L.polyline([camLoc, endpoint], {color: '#098ce4', weight: 2, dashArray: [10, 4]}).addTo(map);
}
```

the mouseover cannot be called when mouse is hover over the circle created. Can advise on this? Thanks!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide a full example displaying the problem. Feel free to use https://leafletjs.com/edit as a base.